# How do I run AppGameKit for Pi, as it seems to be an executable file?

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi-desktop

I am new to StackOverflow so please let me know if I am doing this wrong. I recently got a Raspberry Pi, and have played with it for a little bit. I wanted to use AppGameKit for the Pi on it, but I can't launch the file. The issue seems to be because it is an executable, and it prompts me to select an application to launch it with.

I am very new to all of this, but I thought you can't launch .exe on the Pi? If that's the case, how can I get AppGameKit running

Comment: Did you download a Pi version? Why not ask on their forum https://forum.thegamecreators.com

Comment: https://www.appgamekit.com/agk-pi

Comment: *I am new to StackOverflow so please let me know if I am doing this wrong* - this isn't stackoverflow - so, that's something you're doing wrong

Comment: Hi @Gabe, welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Let's try to help you. What is the AppGameKit? Is it just one package/file that you downloaded? What's the exact name of it? Something like `appgamekit.zip` or `appgamekit.tar.gz`? Or do you follow an installation task to have it available by just calling it with e.g. `appgamekit`? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo, I installed the Pi version, and it was a tar.gz file. I used xarchiver to unzip, but I got an executable out of it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: Is there a link to the *tar.gz*?

Comment: https://www.thegamecreators.com/account/product/list was where I got the download. I've tried both versions available @Ingo